# Add indicators to horizontal scroll in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, scroll

I have the following Horizontal scroll

```
<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <ContentView Content="{Binding DocumentTypeContent}"/>
</ScrollView>
```

But I want that when there's more content to the right there would be an arrow pointing to the right displaying, and when there's more content to the left I'll have the same thing pointing to the left, so for example, the right arrow should always be displaying unless the user scrolled all the way to the right, and the opposite with the left arrow. How can I detect when the scrolls is all the way to the left or all the way to the right to display an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect if scroll touch to end or start like this:

```
 <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled">
```

And your code:

```
 private void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
 {
        double scroll = (sender as ScrollView).ContentSize.Width - (sender as ScrollView).Width;
        if (scroll <= e.ScrollX)
        {
            right_button.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            right_button.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        if (e.ScrollX == 0)
        {
            left_button.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            left_button.IsEnabled = true;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use converter in this situation

```
   <ContentPage
   ...
   xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE">

<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding NUMBEROFITENS,Converter={Helpers:IsBarVisible}}">
    <ContentView Content="{Binding DocumentTypeContent}"/>
</ScrollView>
```

IsBarVisible.cs

```
public class IsBarVisible : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return (int)value > 3 ? "Always" : "Never";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand this will display the scroll bar (or anything that I attach the visibility to this converter) if the number of items in my scrollview are bigger than some number I choose. But my question was related to the position of the scroll being moved by the user, like if there are items to the right that aren't being displayed I will show an image, and if the scroll is all the way to the right I won't show anything. The converter is a good idea, I just need to pass the position of the scroll relative to its size.

Comment: Yeah, my answer isn't a full solution for you, i've posted the answer only for example, but you can consider this a start, you can send more complex info in 'value' field and update the Visibility on every Scrolled event, in this way i think you can achieve the expected result